# Can composite elements contain collections in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

As per [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-incollections), it says:

> The properties of a component can be of any Hibernate type
>   (collections, many-to-one associations, other components, etc). Nested
>   components should not be considered an exotic usage. Hibernate is
>   intended to support a fine-grained object model.

With this statement I understand that I can declare a component with properties that can be collections.

Now again the doc says:

> Composite elements can contain components but not collections. If your
>   composite element contains components, use the
>    tag. This case is a collection of
>   components which themselves have components. You may want to consider
>   if a one-to-many association is more appropriate. Remodel the
>   composite element as an entity, but be aware that even though the Java
>   model is the same, the relational model and persistence semantics are
>   still slightly different.

So here it says **Composite elements can contain components but not collections.** which contradicts with above statement, can someone please explain whether a component can have a collection or not. If possible please provide a small example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No composite element cannot contain collection. But component can. Let me try to explain it this way:

- the first cite is about `<component>` element, while
- the second is about `<composite-element>`

Both of them allow us to map Value Type objects *(as opposite to Reference Type)* - as discussed in a detail here:

- [Understading the restrictions for collection of dependent objects in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637058/)

So, where is the difference? Why the first *(`<component>`)* can contain collections, while the second *(`<composite-element>`)* cannot? Simplified answer would be:

> Because the `<composite-element>` is mapping of the **collection item** already.

The `<component>` on the other hand, is a mapping on the root - `<class>` level.

The full and better answer would be:

> both types do **not** have their ID, their KEY in relational DB structure. That's why they are treated as Value Types - they cannot be referenced.
>
> - The **`<component>`** is in relation one-to-one with its root `<class>` - it has access to the root/class ID. Therefore it could path to collection `<key column="">` the root id.
> - The **`<composite-element>`** does not have access to its ID/Key *(does not exist at all)* and is not on the same level as **`<component>`**. There is no place to cheat as we did with component

So, while we could see mapping like this

```
<class name="eg.Person" table="person">
    <id ...
    ...
    <component name="Name" class="eg.Name" unique="true">
        <parent name="namedPerson"/> //reference back to the Person
        <property name="initial"/>
        <property name="first"/>
        <property name="last"/>

        // here we go 
        // collection mapped inside of the <component>

        <set name="celebrationDates" table="name_Dates">
           <key column="person"/>
          <element column="name" type="date"/>
        </set>
    </component>
</class>
```

With a `<composite-element>` we would end up with a collection item mapping:

```
<class name="eg.Order" .... >
    ....
    <set name="purchasedItems" table="purchase_items" lazy="true">
        <key column="order_id">
        <composite-element class="eg.Purchase">
            <property name="purchaseDate"/>
            <property name="price"/>
            <property name="quantity"/>
            <many-to-one name="item" class="eg.Item"/>

            // this is already component
            // but without ID to be used 
            // as a reference on the other side of bidirectional relation

        </composite-element>
    </set>
</class>
```

Summary, both mappings try to provide similar functionality. They do have different names, because they are used in different scenarios.

*We can imagine that even collection for `<composite-element>` could be working, if we* ... and stop here. If we need that, do not use components. Use full `<class>` mapping.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow, Enjoy Hibernate ;)