# Understading the restrictions for collection of dependent objects in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The [hibernate documentation for dependent collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-incollections) says that:

> There cannot be a reference to the purchase on the other side for
>   bidirectional association navigation. Components are value types and
>   do not allow shared references. A single Purchase can be in the set of
>   an Order, but it cannot be referenced by the Item at the same time.

Can someone please help me in understanding this?

1) Why hibernate restricts the reference of purchase on other side?

2) Why it doesn't allow shared references?

3) What does it mean that a single purchase cannot be referenced by the Item at the same time.?

Can someone please explain this with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain that, I would start with another example from doc:

- [7.3.1. Sorted collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-sorted)

Code snippet shows the mapping of collection of strings:

```
<set name="aliases"
            table="person_aliases" 
            sort="natural">
    <key column="person"/>
    <element column="name" type="string"/>
</set>
```

In this case, we do have a collection of **`aliases`**, represented as a `List<string>`, mapped with an `<element>`.

We can clearly see, that each element here *(alias)* is a `string` - Value Type *(in the meaning of the opposite to the Reference type)*. We also would not expect, that there could be any further place in the system, **referencing** this element...
because it is **not** a **Refeence type**.

Now, let's move to the:

- [9.2. Collections of dependent objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-incollections)

What we see is an example, *(very)* similar, but instead of `<element>`, it is using the `<composite-element>`:

```
<set name="purchasedItems" table="purchase_items" lazy="true">
    <key column="order_id">
    <composite-element class="eg.Purchase">
        <property name="purchaseDate"/>
        <property name="price"/>
        <property name="quantity"/>
        <many-to-one name="item" class="eg.Item"/> <!-- class attribute is optional -->
    </composite-element>
</set>
```

While for **`string`** we have related object in Java *(string)* - for the above construct, we do need custom type. And that would be a `class Pruchase {}`

But even if this is a custom type - our own class, in this scenario it is represented as a Value Type *(again, as opposite to Reference type)*.

Why? Because it does not have any id, any key - to be referenced. It is construct from Domain modeling point of view. Maybe this cite from that [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-dependentobjects) could help more:

> Like value types, components do not support shared references. In other words, two persons could have the same name, but the two person objects would contain two independent name objects that were only "the same" by value.

Finally:

This is a feature. The fact we can use `<composite-element>` and `<element>`, does not mean, that we must. We still can convert the *Purchase* class into first level citizen, by mapping it as a `<class>`. Then all standard stuff will work again - because it would represent a **Reference Type**...

Comment: Thanks Radim for detailed explanation. So I understand that since it is just a component similar to value types we canot have bidirectional navigation between Purchase & Order, is that correct? Also it would be really helpful if you can answer my 3rd question in my post.

Comment: To answer the 3): "..`purchase` cannot be referenced by the `Item`.." is exactly what I tried to say. Purchase, is mapped as a ValueType `<composite-element>`. Purchase is **not** a Reference type. It cannot be referenced. Even by Item. Item cannot have `List<Purchase>`, because there is no commonly available `<class>` purchase. But if we want that... we can - by converting the `<composite-element>` into `<class>`. Then we will define the Id, and make it Reference Type. So it could be referenced even by Item. Does it help?

Comment: Great ;) Enjoy amazing Hibernate, sir ;)